# Shortest expression in typescript to create object implementing interface

Tags: typescript

Expression to create object implementing interface in typescript could be written in two statements (create + return):

```
=>
{
 const  obj: IStudent = { Id: 1, name: 'Naveed' };  
 return obj;
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish this in one statement / expression?

Something like this, for example:

```
=> return (_: IStudent = { Id: 1, name: 'Naveed' })
```

Comment: Yes, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a type in a return statement (there is a proposal to add a different type assertion that allows checking but does not force a specific type, as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) but that is not yet part of the language).

You could however add a return type to your arrow function: `(): IStudent => ({ Id: 1, name: 'Naveed'  })

You could also create a helper function to help with creating such objects:

```
function asType<T>(value: T) {
  return value;
};

type IStudent = { Id: number, name: string}
let fn = () => asType<IStudent>({ Id: 1, name: 'Naveed' });
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM4BUCeAHApgHnQD4AKAN2QBsRcAuRdASkQG8BYAKEUQCdcoQPJBWq4A3JwC+Ejpyg5ciAJIBlAQBNcYKIgC8rZevpgQAWwBGuHgBpEYZKbqJUUHjDABzSZ0r9EwJH0SZl0iFAwFfFUNLShSFkN6AEZbe0d6AHIAOWQyXFx1DMRJRjEgA)

Note: A regular type assertion (with `as` or `<>`) will type the object but might also allow unintended error to slip through (such as excess properties), although it might still be a decent option in some cases:

```
function asType<T>(value: T) {
  return value;
};

type IStudent = { Id: number, name: string}
let fn = () => ({ Id: 1, name: 'Naveed', wops: "" }) as IStudent;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM4BUCeAHApgHnQD4AKAN2QBsRcAuRdASkQG8BYAKEUQCdcoQPJBWq4A3JwC+Ejpyg5ciAJIBlAQBNcYKIgC8rZevpgQAWwBGuHgBpEYZKbqJUUHjDABzSZ0r9EwJH0SZl0iRBIWQ3oARlt7R3oAcgA5ZDJcXHVE2wB3OGxUegAiIsRJZjRlNRBNbTEgA)